# Explanation on Area Attacks

Tags: area-of-effect, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I am new to M&M 3e, coming from a dnd3.5 career and I am trying to get the rules right before our first session.

My problem is with the Area attacks. While I get it that you get a dodge save VS DC=10+effect's rank. I have two questions:

- After the save, will the defending character also do a Toughness check to reduce the damage further?
- In premade characters, when the effect is listed, how can I see the DC for the ability? Example:
  Hero's Hanbook Deluxe Edition, pg. 302. "The Bola" has an attack named Exploding Bolas (Ranged Burst Area Damage 8). What the dodge DC would be for this ability and how is the final DC produced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Area modifier

Area attacks just remove the attack check and replace it with a dodge resistance check (emphasis mine):

> **No  attack  check  is  needed**;  the  effect simply fills the designated area, based on the type of  modifier.  Potential  targets  in  the  area  are  permitted  a  **Dodge  resistance  check**  (DC  10  +  effect  rank)  to avoid some of the effect.

However, passing this Dodge check simply reduces the rank of the effect by half. Regardless, you still need to do a resistance check against the effect as normal.

### Your example: Exploding Bolas (Ranged Burst Area Damage 8).

First, the target does a Dodge check (DC 10+rank = 18)

- If the target passes this Dodge check, the Damage rank is reduced from 8 to 4, meaning the target now has to do a Toughness check (DC 15 + dmg = 19)
- If the target fails this Dodge check, the Damage is not reduced and the target now has to do a Toughness check against the full damage (DC 15 + dmg = 23)

In either case the target suffers the normal consequences of this Damage Resistance check (which is done with Toughness, thus a Toughness check)

### Damage and Toughness

You saying "a Toughness check to reduce the damage further" makes me think that you might be misunderstanding how damage works, which is understandable since it is very different from damage in dnd.

Damage is simply a Power Effect that has consequences on a failed save as many other types of powers do. If you check the entry on Damage (Attack) in the Powers section, you can see the effects of failing the Toughness check (called Damage Resistance check). That is all Damage effects do and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks,  now I get it. Bonus question: if the area attack is based on a Strength attack, do I also put the Strength bonus on the damage and the DC? @Sdjz

Comment: @Drunken_Guy: Yes. Because it increases the effective ranks. Note, however, that you need to buy ranks in the Extra. So, someone with STR 6 and Burst Damage 4 (Strength-Based) would need to pay 14 PP, 8 PP for the Burst Damage 4 and another 6 PP for the extra ranks of Area. That usually gets notated as something like "Shockwave (Damage 4 [Strength-Based, Burst 10])". At that point, this is a full Rank 10 effect with a Dodge DC of 20 and a base Toughness check of 25 (20 if the Dodge save is successful). There could be partial ranks of Burst, but that's a new question almost.